# How to append to text file that uses a loop?

Tags: c#, winforms

My app takes selected information from a SQL database and puts it into a nicely column formatted text file. The problem I have is if the program crashes or stops for any reason, it will overwrite the previous text when restarted.

I'm trying to use the [example provided by Microsoft here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I can't seem to set it up right.

This is the method I'm using to write the text file

```
private void Output()
    {           
                  string createText = 
                    FormatWidth("Severity", 10) + 
                    FormatWidth("LastNotification", 18) +
                    FormatWidth("FirstNotification", 18) + 
                    FormatWidth("DeviceIP", 18) + 
                    FormatWidth("DeviceInterface", 20) + 
                    "DescriptionShort";

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AlarmData> AlarmDataText in AlarmDictionary)
        {
            createText += Environment.NewLine;
            createText += 
            FormatWidth(AlarmDataText.Value.eventSeverity, 8) + 
            FormatWidth(AlarmDataText.Value.eventLastNotification.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"), 18) +
            FormatWidth(AlarmDataText.Value.eventFirstNotification.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"), 18) + 
            FormatWidth(AlarmDataText.Value.deviceIP, 18) + 
            FormatWidth(AlarmDataText.Value.deviceInterface, 20) + 
            AlarmDataText.Value.descriptionShort;
        }

        File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\*username*\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\NMS_Logger\\NMS_Logger\\bin\\Log.txt", createText);

        Console.WriteLine("File Updated"); //For working verification


    }//end Output()
```

Comment: So you want it to continue where it left off *all* the time, or just in the case of a crash? This whole use case seems off, its doing exactly what it should.

Comment: Yes I want it to continue where it left off all the time. This will be run for specific time frames, say like a week. I'm expecting this file to get to about 1TB in size.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use `File.WriteAllText` if you want to append, so I would do something like this:

```
StreamWriter sw;
if (!File.Exists(outputPath)
{
    sw = new StreamWriter(outputPath, false);
    sw.WriteLine(headers);
}
else
    sw = new StreamWriter(outputPath, true);

foreach (...)
   sw.WriteLine(dataLine);
```

You *could* initialize the `StreamWriter` to always append on declaration, but it would have broken the "previous file exists" logic, so I set it up a bit different than usual.

As a side note, you are doing a *lot* of string concatenation, consider using `StringBuilder` instead. If you stick with that approach, you *could* use `File.AppendAllText` instead of writing each line individually in the `foreach`. Note that this approach is very memory-inefficient compared to just writing each line to the file (thanks @Servy).

Also, if the program crashes, you'll have a "junk" line in the middle that will be non-trivial to detect (in order to put the newline in). You may want to always insert a new line before you start appending, even though that would cause a weird line break in the data under normal circumstances.

Comment: Could I use File.AppendAllText if the file is already created? http://pastebin.com/0Wk99BcR Link to what I've changed it too

Comment: @ChrisPBacon Yes, that approach would work as well (though you still need to account for not writing the headers each time).

Comment: Writing each line out to a file is going to perform quite a bit better than using a SB.  It'll tend to have less overhead, and alters the memory footprint from O(n) to O(1).

Comment: @Servy Thank you for those comments, I incorporated them into the part relating the potential use of SB/AppendAllText

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Your comment on SB is confusing me a bit, are you saying using SB IS more efficient memory wise or ISN'T and stick with the concatenation? Also what does (headers) relate to in my code?

Comment: @ChrisPBacon Using SB is better than concatenation, but our point is that instead of holding the entire contents of the file in memory, then writing it all out, its better to create and write each file one at a time. My point with the headers is that you couldn't simply switch out `WriteAllText` for `AppendAllText` in your original code and expect it to work.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I see what you two are saying now. This file can be terribly inefficiently large. This program will run infrequently and it's designed almost intentionally to be a pain in the a** to deal with. In your example, what is the dataline? This is how I've changed it. Just unsure of the dataline http://pastebin.com/eMLqDLWH

Comment: @ChrisPBacon In my example, `dataLine` would be a single "row" of text. That is, what is generated by a single iteration of the original `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether file exists before placing the using the c# file exist function or create a new file with different name each time you run the application